# Show backslash instead of currency symbol on UI

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, cjk

I was trying to print \ on a WPF TextBlock, but I got the currency symbol instead. I figured this is because the system is a CJK Windows, so added the culture info code.

```
CultureInfo useng = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = useng;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = useng;
```

The problem was still there, and I ran out of ideas so I used this deliciously broken workaround.

```
CultureInfo useng = new CultureInfo("en-US");
useng.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "\\";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = useng;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = useng;
```

I was wondering if there is a proper way to fix this.

The code for updating the TextBlock uses TextBlock.Text in a Timer object and takes a Char object from a List, with the Char declared as '\\'

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { tb.Text = "" + listCharEnumerator.Current; }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render);
```

[Code in full available on github. Small project, really.](https://github.com/dare0021/DiarizationGroundTruthTool/blob/currencySymbolBug/DiarizationGroundTruthTool/MainWindow.xaml.cs)

Note the aforementioned workaround is not working on this branch.

Comment: Show how you populate the text block and any relevent XAML

Comment: @ScottChamberlain done! Nothing interesting in the XAML though. Just the default code generated by Visual Studio.

Comment: If you have not done anything to the XAML than it is not the currency. It is far more likely that `listCharEnumerator.Current` does not hold the value you expect it to. Especially being a enumerator and the fact that you are calling it in a dispatcher, try `var temp = listCharEnumerator.Current; Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { tb.Text = "" + temp; }), ...);` you likey have a variable capture issue

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That appears to have been the problem, although I'm not sure how. The '\\' item is never changed to the currency symbol or anything else after it's initially created. Odd.

Comment: I turned my comment in to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of your problem is `listCharEnumerator.Current` is changing while you wait for the dispatcher to run, so by the time the dispatcher gets a chance to run it has moved off of `\\` and moved on to what is likely the last item in the collection (probably the currency symbol).

The way you solve this is get the value of the enumerator in to a local variable before the dispatcher then use the local variable inside the dispatcher.

```
var temp = listCharEnumerator.Current;
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { tb.Text = "" + temp; }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render);
```

Comment: The odd bit is the currency symbol is not used in the code at all, leading me to believe the only way it got there is the system incorrectly assuming I meant the currency symbol when it saw the backslash. It's a small project for now (~300 lines, only one logic file) so it's not like it's hiding anywhere. Probably.

Comment: It is in there, it is likely the last value of `listCharEnumerator` what is the data source? are you sure it is not there?

Comment: Also, using raw enumerators are vary rare, why are you not just using a `foreach(char currentChar in yourCharDataSoruce {...})`

Comment: I was using it to have a constantly updated TextBlock to check if the code was running or not. I replicated the issue in a branch [here (github)](https://github.com/dare0021/DiarizationGroundTruthTool/blob/currencySymbolBug/DiarizationGroundTruthTool/MainWindow.xaml.cs)

Comment: Aaaand the workaround I posted originally doesn't work for that branch. Yay.

Comment: Yea, I don't know why you are getting the curency symbol, but add in the temp variable or switch to a [`DispatcherTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx) and get rid of the `Dispatcher.Invoke` and at least that fixes one potential bug.